# Master Data Web Service

Tags: c#, webservice, wcf

Hola espero estén todos bien, tengo un pequeño problema con una app web que estoy intentando hacer en C# y que consume el servicio web del Master Data Services, en concreto cuando corro el programa este es el error que me aparece

> "Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) authentication failed. The
>   server may not be running in an account with identity
>   'http://domain:port'. If the server is running in a service account
>   (Network Service for example), specify the account's
>   ServicePrincipalName as the identity in the EndpointAddress for the
>   server. If the server is running in a user account, specify the
>   account's UserPrincipalName as the identity in the EndpointAddress for
>   the server"

el programa lo estoy corriendo desde una maquina local, mientras el web service se encuentra en un servidor dentro de la misma red, el codigo es mas o menos el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.ServiceModel;
using MasterDataWS.mdsws;


namespace MasterDataWS
{
    class Program
    {
        private static ServiceClient mdsProxy;
        public static string mdsURL = "http://domain:port/service/service.svc";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            try
            {
                mdsProxy = clientProxy(mdsURL);
                Console.WriteLine("Conection Success");
                createEntityMember("Test_Model", "Version_1", "WSTest", "Nombre", "1", MemberType.Leaf);
                Console.WriteLine("Publish Success");
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        //Clase Proxy

        private static ServiceClient clientProxy(string serverURL)
        {
            WSHttpBinding wsBinding = new WSHttpBinding();            
            EndpointAddress pointAddress = new EndpointAddress(serverURL);

            return new ServiceClient (wsBinding, pointAddress);

        }

        //Crear entity members

        private static void createEntityMember(string modelName, string version, string entityName, string newName, string newCode, MemberType memberType)
        {
            EntityMembersCreateRequest createRequest = new EntityMembersCreateRequest();
            createRequest.Members = new EntityMembers();
            createRequest.ReturnCreatedIdentifiers = true;
            createRequest.Members.ModelId = new Identifier { Name = modelName };
            createRequest.Members.VersionId = new Identifier { Name = version };
            createRequest.Members.EntityId = new Identifier { Name = entityName };
            createRequest.Members.MemberType = memberType;
            createRequest.Members.Members = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Member> { };
            Member newMember = new Member();
            newMember.MemberId = new MemberIdentifier() { Name = newName, Code = newCode, MemberType = memberType };

            createRequest.Members.Members.Add(newMember);
            EntityMembersCreateResponse createResponse = mdsProxy.EntityMembersCreate(createRequest);
            handleOperationErrors(createResponse.OperationResult);

        }

        //Manejador de errores
        private static void handleOperationErrors (OperationResult result)
        {
            string errorMessage = string.Empty;
            if(result.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(Error anError in result.Errors)
                {
                    errorMessage += "Operation Error: " + anError.Code + " " + anError.Description + "\n";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
                Exception ex = new Exception(errorMessage);
                throw ex;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Saludos Alexx13, bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo visitar https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio, de paso obtienes la primera medalla :D

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes, tenemos:

```
http://domain:port
```

Ese debería ser reemplazado por el (domain) dominio y el port (puerto)
donde vive la aplicación, es decir, si tienes un dominio llamado "empresa.com" y el puerto donde la aplicación está enviando y recibiendo información es el 8087, queda de la siguiente manera:

```
http://empresa.com:8087
```

La URL (endpoint) donde apuntes sería:

```
http://empresa.com:8087/service/service.svc
```

Ahora bien, si el servicio lo estás ejecutando en local, revisa en qué puerto tienes la aplicación corriendo, quedaría así:

```
http://localhost:port/services/service.svc
```

Comment: Hola Fredy, el dominio y puerto están, solo quise evitar ponerlos ya que la empresa es algo estricta en cuanto al tema de seguridad, pero la direccion es algo asi http://empresa.net:8001/service/service.svc, de antemano me disculpo por no aclararlo desde un principio y muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta

Comment: normal hermano, de nada. Revisa el enlace que te comenté en tu pregunta y seguimos con el tema :D